# Changing UIButton frame disconnects it from IBAction selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, drawrect, ibaction

I have a xib file which contains a `UIButton`. I control + dragged the button to create an action. The position of the button has to be set dynamically. The method below is called from `drawRect:` method which updates the button position.

```
-(void)updateButtonPosition {
    CGFloat xPos = self.label.frame.origin.x + self.label.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat yPos = self.label.frame.origin.y + self.label.frame.size.height - 25;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height);
    self.button.frame = frame;
}
```

But I noticed that calling this function disconnects the `UIButton` from the action I created by control + dragging (i.e. nothing happens when I click the button when the app is running). I commented the part where this function was called. And now the button started working and the action method was called. So changing the frame **disconnected** the UIButton from its action method.

EDIT: User Interaction is enabled for all its superview. I'm not using auto layout. The project is like that.

How can I change the frame of the button so that the action is also called when I click the button?

Comment: Try to bring your button to front.

Comment: Its already in the very front.

Comment: how do you know it is __disconneted__? has the action removed completely? I hardly believe that this method would do anything like that, so could you elaborate please? it is more likely when you update the bounds then you put the button outside of its superview bounds.

Comment: @holex see my answer.

Comment: @oye, no need to thank for my help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My button's frame was outside the frame of its parent view. Hence it was not tap able.

For more info refer [UIButton not responding after set frame within UIScrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110007/uibutton-not-responding-after-set-frame-within-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

Check the button's frame with it's superview frame. The button receives touch events only when it resides inside it's superview frame.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem, I dragged an action named "btnAction" and a outlet named "btnTest".

This is ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnTest;

@end
```

And this is ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
//    [super viewDidLoad];
//    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(grHandler)]];
}

-(void)grHandler{
    NSLog(@"grHandler actived.");
    [self updateButtonPosition];
}

- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"btn actived.");
}

-(void)updateButtonPosition {
    CGFloat xPos = 20;
    CGFloat yPos = 30;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, self.btnTest.frame.size.width, self.btnTest.frame.size.height);
    self.btnTest.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

Try to use my code and tell me where is the problem?

Then I can help you.

Comment: Action method is working but `grHandler` is never called. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Ok its working. I had to tap on the view. :D I still don't know what the problem is. Here's my project https://ufile.io/d6411

Comment: Can not get your code file, can you put it on GitHub, then I don't need to download it.

Comment: Got it finally.